# Using Raspberry Pi instead of Atmel SAMA5D3

Tags: embedded-linux, raspberry-pi3

I intend to pursue this course from Free-Electrons (https://free-electrons.com/training/embedded-linux/) as a self-learner. They use Atmel SAMA5D3 Xplained board. My question is: can I use Raspberry Pi 3 instead of the Atmel board for completing the labs? If yes, would it be too much effort for someone who is almost a newbie in this field?

A comparison between the two boards can be found here (in Italian): http://www.campana.vi.it/blog/confronto-raspberry-pi3-beaglebone-black-sama5d3-xplained/. Rasp Pi3 seems to win in almost every respect, except for the number of GPIO pins and the price of Pi is around £30 vs £79 for Atmel (checked today). I'd really love it if the Pi could be used for this course.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: A quick review of the 500+ slides of the PDF course indicates that it's primarily a generic presentation, with only a handful of slides that are actually Atmel/Microchip specific.  Potential stumbling blocks for you would be connecting a serial console, understanding the boot sequence of the Broadcom SoC, and knowing the proper configuration files for building the toolchain, U-Boot, and the Linux kernel.  RPi does not have any raw flash storage, so that aspect of embedded systems cannot be experimented with.  Regardless of the board, IMO a newbie could have problems self-learning all of this.

Comment: *"Rasp Pi3 seems to win in almost every respect ..."* --  The big negative against the RPi (with its Broadcom SoCs) (and also clones that use Allwinner SoCs) is that the technical documentation is sparse to non-existent.  If you intend to stay at the user/application-level, there's little concern.  But if you want to learn about the integrated peripherals of the SoC, then you'll appreciate authentic board schematics and the 2000 pages of a technical/programmer's reference manual or datasheet by Texas Instruments or Microchip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sawdust stated, the main parts that will differ are the u-boot and kernel labs because they are specific to the SoC and board. They may not be so easy to adapt. The main issue is that they are all about getting a system booting on the platform so the followings labs depend on them.

The buildroot lab will differ a bit because of the different SoC but is way easier to adapt. Also, you won't be able to do the "Filesystems - Flash file systems" lab at all because the RPi doesn't have any NAND flash. That is one of the main reason why we are using the SAMA5D3 Xplained.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Thanks also to @sawdust for his comments.